# CIMaskedVariableBlur creates unwanted border

Tags: ios, ciimage

I am using the following function to blur an image with depth map and noticed that the filter creates a border around the end result image. I am not sure what did I do wrongly that create this.

```
func blur(image: CIImage, mask: CIImage, orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up) -> UIImage? {
    
    let invertedMask = mask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")
    let output = image.applyingFilter("CIMaskedVariableBlur", parameters: ["inputMask" : invertedMask,"inputRadius": 15.0])
    
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you likely want to say:

```
func blur(image: CIImage, mask: CIImage, orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up) -> UIImage? {

    let invertedMask = mask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")
    let output = image.applyingFilter("CIMaskedVariableBlur", parameters: ["inputMask" : invertedMask,"inputRadius": 15.0])

    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: image.extent) else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
}
```

Where you are drawing in the extent of the original image. `CIMaskedVariableBlur` will set the extent to include all of the pixels sampled which will likely include pixels that you are not concerned particularly along the edges where color values are averaged with values outside the bounds of the original image.

Comment: Yeah, The result is better but still have abit of border on the edges (maybe about 3 pixel thick). Any idea how I might be able to get rid of it totally

Comment: You rock man, had the exact same issue and your answer fixed it completely.